# How can I repeat $ in TCL language?

Tags: tcl

My code is

```
    set a "00"
    set lst$a {1 2 3 4 5}

    puts $lst00
    puts $lst$a   <- it doesn't work
```

I guess "puts $lst$a" should be converted to "puts $(lst$a) or somthing like that"

What's the answer? Plz help me~

```
    puts $(lst$a)  <- it doesn't work
    puts $"lst$a"  <- it doesn't work
    puts ${lst$a}  <- it doesn't work
```

Comment: You just have to remember that `$` is just shorthand for the `set` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Tcl command "set" to do de-reference. For example:

```
puts [set lst$a]  ;# Same as "puts $lst00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
puts [set lst$a]
```

Tcl's substitution rules are documented at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm